# Are both of these statements equivalent?

Tags: c, if-statement

statement 1

```
return (x1 > x2) ? ((x1 > x3) ? x1: x3): ((x2 > x3) ? x2: x3);
```

statement 2

```
if(x1>x2){
    if(x1>x3){
        return x1;
    }
    else{
        return x3;
    }
}
else if(x2>x3){
    return x2;
}
else return x3;
```

Comment: Obfuscated C code mode enabled.

Comment: Both are far harder to read than: `int largest = x1; if (x2 > largest) largest = x2; if (x3 > largest) largest = x3; return largest;` (where the type `int` is assumed, but can be the (common?) scalar type of `x1`, `x2`, `x3` — a type for which `>` is defined).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are equivalent, provided the types of `x1`, `x2` and `x3` are all the same.  If types are different but convertible to the return type, then statement 1 will result in a compilation error.

Comment: The question was about C, not C++.

Comment: Whoops, I thought I had my C++ search on :/  I have removed the C++ recommendation.

Comment: If the types are arithmetic, the usual arithmetic conversions apply to ternary expressions. I can't think of any cases in C where `x1 > x3` is valid but `(x1 > x3) ? x1 : x3` is not.

Comment: Disagree that " statement 1 will result in a compilation error."  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55014093/2410359)

Answer (score 3):

> Are both of these statements equivalent?

With variant types: possibly no.

Example: The `a ? b : c` causes `b` and `c` to covert to a common type, yet not so with `if then else`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

double foo(int x1, float x2, int x3) {
  // Inexact conversions to float      vv                      vv
  return (x1 > x2) ? ((x1 > x3) ? x1 : x3) : ((x2 > x3) ? x2 : x3);
}

double bar(int x1, float x2, int x3) {
  if (x1 > x2) {
    if (x1 > x3) {
      return x1;
    } else {
      return x3;
    }
  } else if (x2 > x3) {
    return x2;
  } else
    return x3;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%f\n", foo(INT_MAX, 1.0f, 0));
  printf("%f\n", bar(INT_MAX, 1.0f, 0));
}
```

Output

```
2147483648.000000
2147483647.000000
```

---

Or possibly a compiler error under both approaches.

```
double foo2(int x1, float x2, int *x3) {
  // error: invalid operands to binary > (have 'float' and 'int *')
  return (x1 > x2) ? ((x1 > x3) ? x1 : x3) : ((x2 > x3) ? x2 : x3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are equivalent.

Starting with the inner `if`:

```
if(x1>x3){
    return x1;
}
else{
    return x3;
}
```

This is the same as:

```
return (x1 > x3) ? x1 : x3;
```

Let's call the above expression `X`:

Now looking at the outer if / else if /else:

```
if(x1>x2){
    return X;
}
else if(x2>x3){
    return x2;
}
else return x3;
```

This becomes:

```
return (x1>x2) ? X : ((x2>x3) ? x2 : x3);
```

Substituting in `X`:

```
return (x1 > x2) ? ((x1 > x3)? x1 :x3) : ((x2 > x3) ? x2 : x3);
```

This can be a bit more clear if you split this up over multiple lines:

```
return (x1 > x2) ? ((x1 > x3)? 
                       x1 :
                       x3) : 
       (x2 > x3) ? x2 : x3;
```

If the there were only one level of `if` statements I might go with the ternary operator, but because the levels are nested I would stick with the more explicit  set of statements for clarity.